# How do I pass multiple variables through a URL in Javascript

Tags: javascript, url

Folks,

First question here and trying to teach myself js and jquery, please forgive (or correct) any errors in nomenclature....

I am happily managing to pass through a variable from one page to another with this piece of code:

```
function openPage() {window.open('datapage_test.html?id=' + dataset[0].Var_Name)}
```

returns: `file:///*path*/datapage_test.html?id=UK_Wakefield`

When I try and extend this to pass multiple variables through I fail:

```
function openPage() {
    window.open('datapage_test.html?id=' + dataset[0].Var_Name + dataset[0].Var_Class + dataset[0].Var_Instance )
}
```

returns:
`file:///C:/*path*/datapage_test.html?id=WakefieldundefinedUK`

All pointers gratefully received.
J

Comment: It seems that `dataset[0].Var_Class` is `undefined`. Make sure you've spelled the property's name (`Var_Class`) correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Urls are configure like this:

```
http://www.example.com/images/assets/file.html?id=1&type=2
protocol://domainName.com/path/to/myFile.html?parameter=value&other=value
```

This is your important part you are trying to do `?parameter=value&other=value`

You can try something like this:

```
  function openPage() {window.open('datapage_test.html?id=' + dataset[0].Var_Name +'&val2=' + dataset[0].Var_Class +'&val3=' + dataset[0].Var_Instance )}
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting variables in urls is done with `?` which is what you are doing, however, for variables after that, you use `&`. For example, if I have the variables cat = meow and dog = woof, you could do `http://example.com/?cat=meow&dog=woof`.

Also, might want to check `dataset[0].Var_Class`. Apparently it's undefined in your example.